# Rails ActiveRecord: Missing column in grouping query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
Key.select('products.name as product, product_groups.name as product_group, AVG(keys.cost) as cost')
.group('products.id, product_groups.id')
.left_joins(:product,:product_group)
```

the result:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Key id: nil, cost: 0.6e1>, #<Key id: nil, cost: 0.4e1>]>
```

Expected return 3 field, but returnig value: 2 field.

---

```
I found the solution. The detail areas in the console did not appear as HASH.
```

Comment: What data is in each table? And what SQL is being generated? (You can easily see this by checking the log, or adding `.to_sql` to the end of the query.)

Comment: SELECT products.name as product, product_groups.name as product_group, AVG(keys.cost) as cost 
FROM keys 
LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.id = keys.product_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_groups ON product_groups.id = keys.product_group_id 
GROUP BY products.id, product_groups.id

Comment: ...And what data is in each table? [Edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43629465/edit) to include all information. It it much easier to answer questions that provide a [Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ProductGroups: id, name
Products: id, products_group_id, name
Key: id, key, products_group_id, product_id, cost

Comment: **Data**. What **data** is in your tables? I cannot reproduce your problem without knowing what **values** are in the `product_groups`, `products` and `keys` tables. And again, all information should please be placed [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43629465/edit), not buried in the comments.

Comment: @TomLord The same sql works correctly in PGAdmin.

Comment: I found the solution. The detail areas in the console did not appear as HASH.

Comment: ...And there was no way I was ever going to be able to find that answer, because you never supplied any **data** in your question above. Next time, please, post a question that is **complete** and **verifiable**.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding the grouping statement would only return Aggregated columns and columns that are used to group the data set. In your case you have not used the grouping columns in the select list but, some other fields. As a result you don't receive the other two columns.

Comment: I found the solution. The detail areas in the console did not appear as HASH.