# Rails Active Record: Missing column in group query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, group-by, aggregate-functions

I saw that someone had the same question but the solution was not clear to me:
[Rails ActiveRecord: Missing column in grouping query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629465/rails-activerecord-missing-column-in-grouping-query)

I wrote a query in Active Record as follows:

```
    shortened_urls.joins(:visits)
                .group(:short_url, :long_url)
                .select('long_url, short_url, COUNT(visits.id) as number_of_visits')
                .order(Arel.sql('COUNT(visits.id) DESC'))
                .limit(5)
```

And I get the following results:

```
[#<ShortenedUrl:0x00005585fbb8fb60
  id: nil,
  long_url: "jfjfhgfhduiuyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.k",
  short_url: "Bn_N2QPoSE1VlNYqWXUL9A">,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00005585fbb8f9f8
  id: nil,
  long_url:
   "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL#restarting_the_server",  
  short_url: "Dte6_CUnAdxJgv_jUBwXIg">,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00005585fbb8f8b8
  id: nil,
  long_url: "jjjfhusirtyuizyfsvqdhjdhdfv",
  short_url: "CQa8n1o-f2oEwKy8j_Zo9Q">,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00005585fbb8f778
  id: nil,
  long_url: "uezfhueizyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.kkkk",
  short_url: "4S1uC8yl0a8HlK6xJq23FQ">,
 #<ShortenedUrl:0x00005585fbb8f638
  id: nil,
  long_url: "blahffhhfhfhhfhfhffhfhhfhhfhfhfhfhhfhfh.com",
  short_url: "_NZSroaeyvVqvOKoPAieng">]
```

As you can see, the column 'number_of_visits' doesn't appear and the id's are all nil;

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this ? Or maybe explain to me what was the solution for the other similar question posted?

Thank you very much

Comment: `number_of_visits` is a SQL alias as isn't going to appear in the result you receive from that query, it will be available as a method for each of the objects inside that result, you can check it with `your_query[0].number_of_visits`. As per the id, you have to add it to the select method.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It's more clear now.